# Polya-MacMahon-Burnside's generating function at "-1"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

$\mathbb{Z}_n$, as a cyclic subgroup of symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$, acts on $[n] :=\{1, 2,\dots,n\}$. Hence $\Bbb{Z}_n$ permutes the elements of the Boolean algebra $2^{[n]}$ of all subsets of $[n]$, and also permutes the subsets $\binom{[n]}i$ of a given cardinality $i$.

Consider the following generating function (attributed to Polya-MacMahon-Burnside) which counts $\Bbb{Z}_n$-orbits according to their cardinality. Letting $S$ be an element in the orbit $\overline{S}$, the statement reads
$$f_n(x)=\sum\limits_{\substack{ \text{orbits $\overline{S}$} \\ \overline{S}\in 2^{[n]}/\Bbb{Z}_n }} x^{\vert S\vert},$$
where $2^{[n]}/\Bbb{Z}_n$ is a quotient complex.

> **Question.** Are there nice interpretations (combinatorial, geometric, etc) of $f_n(-1)$?

Comment: does section 6 of "The cyclic sieving phenomenon" by Reiner, Stanton and White fit?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting interpretation that I like to share.

**Note.** In the present case, the orbits can be interpreted as necklaces. Therefore, we may write
$$f_n(x)=\frac1n\sum_{d\vert n}\varphi(d)\left(1+x^d\right)^{\frac{n}d}.$$
In *Supersymmetry and Combinatorics*, [Onofri-Veneziano-Wosiek](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0603082.pdf) introduced a supersymmetric quantum mechanical model for a system with fermionic and bosonic freedom. By applying [Pauli's exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle), the authors are able to find a formula to enumerate what they call *forbidden necklaces*. Curious enough, we may translate their result to be exactly the value of the function $f_n(x)$ at $x=-1$; namely that
$$f_n(-1)=\frac1n\sum
\limits_{\substack{d\vert n\\ \text{$d$ even}}}\varphi(d)\cdot 2^{\frac{n}d}$$
counts the number of forbidden necklaces.